# Tesseract Multiple language configs

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract with `-l eng+chi_sim`

I am able to set up [word lists](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#dictionaries-word-lists-and-patterns) and patterns in tesseract. However I would like to disable loading system dictionaries for only one language but keep it enabled for another.

Specifically I would like to turn off dictionary for english but load all the chinese dictionaries. Is it possible to have such a configuration setting?